# Can someone explain to me why $\frac{sin(\theta)}{sin(\frac{\theta}{2})}=2cos(\frac{\theta}{2})$

Tags: trigonometry

Can someone explain to me why $$\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})}=2\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})$$

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use the formula $\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x$. Let $x=\frac{\theta}{2}$. More generally, $\sin (a+b)=\sin a\cos b+\sin b\cos a$.

Comment: Use the formula $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$.

Comment: @kimchilover How does that help?

Comment: Use Euler's identity, most useful for nearly all related questions: $e^{i\phi}=\cos\phi+i\sin\phi$.

Comment: @Wojowu What Gyro Gearloose said is exactly what I had in mind. The ratio in question $(a^2-b^2)/(a-b)$ where $a=\exp(i\theta/2)$ and $b=1/a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the identity $$\sin(\theta)=2\sin\bigg(\frac{\theta}{2}\bigg)\cos\bigg(\frac{\theta}{2}\bigg)$$ Putting this into your equation we get $$\frac{2\sin\bigg(\frac{\theta}{2}\bigg)\cos\bigg(\frac{\theta}{2}\bigg)}{\sin\bigg(\frac{\theta}{2}\bigg)}$$ And you can see that this is equal to $$2\cos\bigg(\frac{\theta}{2}\bigg)$$

Answer (score 0):

Because

$\sin 2 \alpha= 2 \sin \alpha \cos \alpha$

and

$\theta=2\frac{\theta}{2}$

Comment: Thanks a lot I get it now

Answer (score 0):

use that $$\sin(\theta)=2\sin(\theta/2)\cos(\theta/2)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot Dr.

Answer (score 0):

Use the identify of  formula
sin (A+B) = SinACosB+CosASinB.
Put there the same argument.